# Retornar valor desejado dentro de uma função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao tentar retornar o valor do `$("#datepicker-range").val()` no inicio do código, o `console` me dá um valor **vazio**. Logo, me sugeriram fazer um page sniffer porque o motivo do campo não estar capturando a data do campo seria devido um problema na ordem das operações na leitura do código.

```
$(function(){
    startSelectors();

    var datepickerVerify = setInterval(function(){
        if($("#datepicker-range").val()){
            clearInterval(datepickerVerify);
            var vl = $("#datepicker-range").val();
            console.log('value returned: '+vl);
        }
        return vl;
    }, 50);

    //verificando o valor da variavel
    console.log('datepicker=> '+datepickerVerify);
});


function startSelectors(){
    $("#datepicker-range").val('2017-03-01 até 2017-08-02');
};
```

E logo abaixo segue como o console está retornando o meu código (saliento que o campo está funcionando perfeitamente e apresenta aquela mesmo data no front-end)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invés de retornar a data no log do meio, como foi retornado dentro do `if`, ele me retorna um `true` (numero 1). Como posso setar o valor da variável `datepickerVerify` ao invés do `true`, me retornar a data?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Separando o conteúdo da função setInterval em uma rotina separada, o código funcionou perfeitamente. comentei a rotina clearInterval pois o código dela não estava no exemplo. Segue o código:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        startSelectors();

        var datepickerVerify = setInterval();

        //verificando o valor da variavel
        console.log('datepicker=> '+datepickerVerify);
    });

function setInterval(){
            if($("#datepicker-range").val()){
                //clearInterval(datepickerVerify);
                var vl = $("#datepicker-range").val();
                console.log('value returned: '+vl);
            }
            return vl;
};

function startSelectors(){
    $("#datepicker-range").val('2017-03-01 até 2017-08-02');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, este comportamento se deve ao fato de você estar utilizando o setInterval, que pela característica dele, inicia um processamento em paralelo com a execução do código principal.

O comportamento do interpretador foi esse:
1. Chamou e executou a função startSelectors
2. Criou uma nova instância para executar a função passada no setInterval após 50 milisegundos
3. Imprimiu o console.log

Porém quando ele executa a etapa 2, ele não aguarda a contagem do tempo de 50 milisegundos para prosseguir com a execução, ele segue em frente até o fim e em paralelo executa o setInterval após o tempo configurado.

Isso fica visível inclusive no console, que imprime primeiro o console.log de fora do setInterval para depois imprimir o console.log de dentro do setInterval, porque ele foi executado justamente depois.

Para resolver isso, analise se realmente precisa deste setInterval, pois retirando ele você volta a uma linha de execução linhar. Caso realmente seja necessário, você terá que prosseguir com a lógica dentro do setInterval ou com uma chamada de função em callback, como no exemplo abaixo:

```html
$(function(){
    startSelectors();

    setInterval(function(){
        if($("#datepicker-range").val()){
            clearInterval(datepickerVerify);
            var vl = $("#datepicker-range").val();
            console.log('value returned: '+vl);
        }
        continuacao(vl);
        //return vl;
    }, 50);

    //verificando o valor da variavel
    function continuacao(datepickerVerify) {
      console.log('datepicker=> '+datepickerVerify);
    }
});


function startSelectors(){
    $("#datepicker-range").val('2017-03-01 até 2017-08-02');
};
```